# Form not getting submitted with jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I've got a little problem while using jQuery validation plugin in on my .net/MVC projects. The validation generally works all fine, the issue arises at the time of submitting: I want form not be submitted when there are any validation errors in it and for this I set `debug:true`.

But after setting it to true when the submit button becomes unresponsive, even when everything is fine i.e. no validation errors, nothing just happens while clicking the submit button. And if remove debug:true it submits the form even when there are validation errors in it.

I want a solution to this problem, the middle way i.e. when clicking submit if there are errors it doesn't submits the form and shows errors. And if there are no errors then it just simple submits it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
$("#productSubmit").validate( {
  debug : true, rules : {
     prdctttle : {
        maxlength : 50, 
        required : true, 
        onlyChars : true }
     , prdctdscrptn : {
        maxlength : 250, 
        required : true, 
        onlyChars : true }
    }
  , messages : {
     }
  }
); 
}
); 
$.validator.addMethod('onlyChars', function (value) {
return /^[a-zA-Z ,-!]+$/.test(value); }, 'Please enter a valid name with only alphabets');
   $("#productSubmit").validate( {
  submitHandler : function(form) {
     if ($(form).valid()) form.submit(); return false; // prevent normal form posting
     }
  }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your last line to check if the form is valid before submitting:

```
$("#productSubmit").validate({ 
    submitHandler: function(form) {  
                           if ($(form).valid()) 
                               form.submit(); 
                           return false; // prevent normal form posting
                    }
 });
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to add the "return false;" line to stop the form submitting normally (so it only happens when the validation passes).

Comment: i changed the list line with your code, but now the whole validation script has stopped working.. and when am clicking submit without entering nethng its jst refreshing and when am submitting after correctly filling all the info. the browser giving `"This web page is not available"` error

Comment: @Maven Darn, I had a feeling that might happen. Try my updated code.

Comment: @DGregL , still facing some weired behavior, Now if i try submitting an empty forms it gives fine validation errors of 'This field is required', but after i filled the form and try submitting the submit button becomes irresponsive as before. plus its not rechecking for validation onchange of its value like before.. :s

Comment: Ive updated the code in my post.. incase there is some syntax mistake in it now..

Answer (score 3):

GregL's answer is correct for the most part.

What ultimately got this working correctly for me was also the addition of:

```
onsubmit: false
```

Final code:

```
$("#productSubmit").validate({ 
 onsubmit: false,
 submitHandler: function(form) {  
   if ($(form).valid())
   {
       form.submit(); 
   }
   return false; // prevent normal form posting
 }
});
```

This overrides the default submit behaviour, and handles the final validation check and submission within the submitHandler.